# Loading ASP response data in HTML Select list

Tags: html, jquery, asp-classic

I have an HTML form where I use a $.get to call an ASP page and receive back the HTML code for option values of a select list.  The data getting returned is correct in what I was expecting, but I cannot seem to get it to load the select list.

JAVASCRIPT

```
    function PopulateServerList() {

    var storenum = document.getElementById("iStoreNumber").value;
    var ASP = "ListSupervisors2.asp?q=" + storenum;
    $.get(ASP, function(response) {
    alert(response);
    document.getElementById("iSupervisor").innerHTML = reponse;
    }); 
}
```

ASP

```
sql="SELECT * FROM SUPERVISORS WHERE STORE="
sql=sql & "'" & request.querystring("q") & "'"

set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;User ID=<ID>;Password=<Password>;Initial Catalog=SUPERVISOR;Data Source=<Server>"
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

rs.Open sql,conn

do until rs.EOF
  for each x in rs.Fields
Response.Write "<option value=''" & x.value &"''>"& x.value &"</option>"
next
rs.MoveNext
loop
```

I'm really new at this so hopefully I'm not making a really easy mistake.

I'm also trying to figure out how to set the two columns I receive back from the DB as the value and text of the select list in the ASP, but I'm more worried about loading the list at this point.

Comment: And `iSupervisor` is the id of the required select element.

Comment: Yeah.  sorry should have put in the html for that

Comment: and pay no attention to the fact I misspelled response in the 7th line of the javascript code.  I have that correct in the actual file

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue is a bug with IE where innerHTML will not fill a select list.  Found a page from Microsoft with a klunky workaround

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found is to use jquery

```
$("#iSupervisor").html(response);
```

pretty much goes right around the problem.